# custom ebtables module && skb manipulation && kernel panic

Tags: linux, module, kernel, panic, ebtables

Some time ago I implemented ebtables module based on vnat module by Ashwin Kashyap (http://www.research.rutgers.edu/~ashwink/misc_projs/ebt_vnat.html). Module can be used in BROUTING chain in broute table for stripping vlan tags and putting vlan id in nf mark. Module also allows adding vlan tags based on nf mark value in POSTROUTING chain of nat table. Module doesn't have any problems with working on bridged traffic. System is rock solid stable. Problem starts as soon as I add tproxy interception into the mix. This results in kernel panic AFTER some time of operation. I stress the fact that I don't see kernel panic after first packet just after few minutes of tproxied traffic streams. It seems that the way I mangle SKBs is not clean enough for L3+ processing. BTW I'm working on 2.6.32 kernel. Please find critical parts of the module with comments below:

```
// code for adding vlan tag based on skb->mark value
if (!skb_make_writable(skb, 0))
  return EBT_DROP;

if(skb->mark > 0){
  // maybe we should always seek VLAN_HLEN+ETH_HLEN instead of using condition?
  if (skb_headroom(skb) < (skb->mac_len == 0 ? VLAN_HLEN + ETH_HLEN : VLAN_HLEN ) ) {
    struct sk_buff *sk_tmp = skb;
    skb = skb_realloc_headroom(sk_tmp, VLAN_HLEN );
    kfree_skb(sk_tmp);

    if (skb == NULL) {
      return EBT_DROP;
    }
  }

  // we need 4 more bytes for 802.1q header, so push!...I can almost see the head(er)
  skb_push(skb, VLAN_HLEN);

  skb->mac_header-=VLAN_HLEN;
  skb->network_header-=VLAN_HLEN;
  skb->transport_header-=VLAN_HLEN;
  veth = (struct vlan_ethhdr *) eth_hdr(skb);

  // move dst/src mac addresses (12b of header) 4 bytes back to make room for
  // 802.1q header
  memmove( skb->head + skb->mac_header, skb->head + skb->mac_header + VLAN_HLEN, 12);

  // fill 802.1q header
  veth->h_vlan_proto = __constant_htons(ETH_P_8021Q);
  veth_TCI = skb->mark & 0xfff;
  veth->h_vlan_TCI = htons(veth_TCI);      
}

// code for stripping vlan tag and putting it into skb->mark value
veth = (struct vlan_ethhdr *)eth_hdr(skb);
if(veth->h_vlan_proto == __constant_htons(ETH_P_8021Q)){

  if (!skb_make_writable(skb, 0))
    return EBT_DROP;

  // determine vlan id
  vid=(ntohs(veth->h_vlan_TCI) & 0xfff);
  mark = vid;

  // copy dst/src mac addresses (12b) 4 bytes fwd, so it covers 802.1q header
  memmove(skb->head + skb->mac_header + VLAN_HLEN, skb->head + skb->mac_header, 12);

  // adapt header pointers
  skb->mac_header+=VLAN_HLEN;
  skb->mac_len = ETH_HLEN;
  skb->network_header+=VLAN_HLEN;
  skb->transport_header+=VLAN_HLEN;
  skb->data += VLAN_HLEN;
  skb->len -= VLAN_HLEN;

  eth = eth_hdr(skb);
  skb->protocol=eth->h_proto;
}
skb->mark=mark;
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers (as long as they are at least 64bit long). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is supposed to change the MAC header to either add or remove an 802.1q header. Now I could well be wrong here but why do you need to shift the pointers to the network and transport layer headers?

I would expect the MAC header to expand and contract into the skb headroom whilst the rest of the packet remains untouched in either case. Moving the network and transport headers causes the upper layers (3+) to read the wrong first 4 bytes.

(N.B. I would have written this as a comment rather than an answer as I'm not confident I'm right but I've been working on a VLAN tag translation module for ebtables recently and this is the first time I've contributed to SO, so my reputation apparently isn't high enough).